# CSS breaks in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I hae the following CSS selector:

```
.section h1,
.section > div:first-child
{
 background-color: #E5E5E5;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
 padding: 3px;
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

Now I know that the first-child and the > selectors do not work in IE6, but .section h1 does.  My problem is that in IE6, the .section h1 does not get applied because of the .section > div:first-child.  Is there any way to specify both without breaking IE, and without specifying the entire style twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in seperate declarations. OR better yet use a conditional comment to include an ie6 only stylesheet after you main one that contains the same definition for `.section h1` only.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, separate them out as prodigitalson says. Since IE doesn't recognize the ":first-child", it just "jumps" out and continues to the next declaration.